# Material-UI DataGrid (mui): How do I add a tooltip for each row?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I can find solutions to add tooltips for each cells but not for the whole row. Could you please help me ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.